# keeping Firebug active

Tags: httpwebrequest, firebug

I'm trying to capture the traffic upon a form submission.  Firebug prompts the user to "Activate Firebug for the selected Firefox tab".  Of course by the time I click that, it is too late, the HTTP traffic has already passed.  How do I continually capture?

(Edited to add information:) Here's a trivial case that also fails: my root page has a button to request the root (that is the very same page).  Firebug still keeps prompting for activation.  This app is served from localhost.

(Edit:) This might have something to do with Google App Engine.  When I use the CherryPy server on 127.0.0.1:8080 I can capture HTTP traffic in Firebug.  When I used the Google App Engine to serve at localhost:8080 I cannot capture the traffic.

Answer (score 0):

Enable the "Persist" button in Firebug's net panel. If you submit to another site you might have to enable firebug for this site first.

Comment: Persist is not working for me.  The submit requests a new resource and of course the browser screen changes and a "same window" Firebug instance disappears when the new resource is loaded.  Firebug in a different window will prompt "click to activate".

Comment: When Firebug is in it's own window, having Persist on does not seem to change the behaviour wherein I get prompted to "Activate Firebug for the selected Firefox tab".

Comment: If I activate Firebug for both the form page and response page, a second submission of the same form page still causes Firebug to prompt me.

Answer (score 0):

so far, 2013-03-05, it is still a bug for firebug:

[Issue 3484:    Persist button in net panel does not work when following a link to a different site](http://code.google.com/p/fbug/issues/detail?id=3484)

for more detail can refer my post:

[【记录】Firebug的网络（Network）的保持（Persist）不工作](http://www.crifan.com/firefox_firebug_persist_for_network_not_working/)